# Facing an issue about populating the javascript array

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, flask

I have been working on a project which is to create a node.js server and I have to read some text from the file. Then I want to use a Python API to consume these text and get the result back. I have been able to hit these API and get the response successfully.

What have I done till now -
1. Created a node server 
2. read all the file and get the text content from them 
3. create a flask server with appropriate api 
4. hit these API to get the response

**app.js**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request-promise');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Node server')
})

app.get('/postdatatoFlask', function (req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    categories = ['business', 'entertainment']

    // answers SHOULD CONTAIN ALL THE RESPONSES FROM THE FLASK API
    var answers = []

    //iterating over different file 
    categories.forEach(function(category){

        for(var i=100;i<=100;i++){

            //creating the path for the new file to be read 
            var path = 'dataset/'+category+'/'+i.toString()+'.txt';

            //textContent contains the data read from file 
            var textContent = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8')

            //creating the object 
            var data = { content : textContent }

            //posting the data to the flask server on route postdata
            var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/postdata',
                body: data,
                json: true 
            };

            // returndata is the variable contains the data return by flask API
            var returndata
            var sendrequest = request(options)
            .then(function (parsedBody) {
                 // parsedBody contains the data sent back from the Flask server
                returndata = parsedBody;
                answers.push(returndata)
                console.log(returndata) // do something with this data, here I'm assigning it to a variable.
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    })


    console.log('Showing the responses!!!')
    console.log(answers)
    console.log('Stoping the showcase!!!!')

    res.send('done');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**compute.py**

```
import json
import time
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Flask server"

@app.route('/postdata', methods = ['POST'])
def postdata():
    data = request.get_json()
    # print(data['content'])
    textContent = data['content']
    print(textContent)
    print('-- --- -- --- -- -- -- -- -- --')
    return json.dumps({"newdata":textContent})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

**Problem** 
1. In app.js I want to store all the responses in **answer** array but I am unable to populate it. 
2. why output from console.log(returndata) print after console.log(answer)

Comment: `for(var i=100;i<=100;i++)`, is there a typing mistake in this part?

Comment: Why would you want to run a loop just for 1 iteration(`i=100` and then loop terminates)? Why not remove the loop if it serves no purpose?

Comment: I just used it for testing purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/postdata',
    body: data,
    json: true 
};

// returndata is the variable contains the data return by flask API
try {
    // temp.push(await request(options));
    answers.push(await request(options));
    } catch(err) {
    throw err;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. With `answers.push(returndata)`, you are pushing an array inside another array. If you want to concat the content of `returndata` to `answers`, use `answers.push(...returndata)`
2. Javascript has an async, non blocking IO runtime, so here:

```js
var sendrequest = request(options)
            .then(function (parsedBody) {
                 // parsedBody contains the data sent back from the Flask server
                returndata = parsedBody;
                answers.push(returndata)
                console.log(returndata) // do something with this data, here I'm assigning it to a variable.
            })
```

The callback inside `then` is put to the callstack after those:

```js
console.log('Showing the responses!!!')
    console.log(answers)
    console.log('Stoping the showcase!!!!')
```